# NSDictionary + ARC + copy vs reference

Tags: objective-c, ios

These are probably are pretty simple YES|NO type questions.

I have some NSDictionaries containing other NSDictionaries. Let's say **NSDictionary_A** and **NSDictionary_B**. These persist for the life of the app.

The NSDictionaries contained in **NSDictionary_A** are passed by reference to various objects:

`track.instrument = [NSDictionary_A objectForKey:@"Blue"];`

Later it gets changed:

`track.instrument = [NSDictionary_A objectForKey:@"Red"];`

**So first question:** The `@property` instrument is synthesized + retained as `strong` so does the setter for `instrument`set the current value of `instrument` to `nil` before setting the new value, and if so, does this affect the source of the reference in `NSDictionary_A` - in other words, set the reference to `nil'`? Sounds wrong just writing it out.. so I think the answer is **NO** here. Also, it probably doesn't matter that the `@property` instrument is stored as `weak` or `strong` since the reference in `NSDictionary_A1` persists for the app life but since it is a pointer, should be `weak` - **YES**?

**Second question:** An NSDictionary in **NSDictionary_B** is passed to an object but it can change some of the values in that NSDictionary:

`track.playbackType = [NSDictionary_B objectForKey:@"Random"];`
`[track.playbackType objectForKey:@"maxRange"] = 20`;

So should I be making a `copy` of the NSDictionary here because it's values will be changed or am I completely misunderstanding this whole reference passing thang?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting mixed up in how pointers work.

For the first question, "track.instrument" is just a pointer. So it will start as "pointing to nil".

this:

```
track.instrument = [NSDictionary_A objectForKey:@"Blue"];
```

means, "stop pointing to nil and point to that object"

If you can ensure your dictionary will persist for the entire app then it doesnt matter, whatever is at @blue key will never get dealocated. But for the sake of having the correct code, it should be weak.

Edit: Had read the second question incorrectly.

Second question:

about this:

```
track.playbackType = [NSDictionary_B objectForKey:@"Random"];
```

first your pointer points to the **NSDictionary** from the dictionary.

```
[track.playbackType objectForKey:@"maxRange"] = 20;
```

Since it is a NSDictionary this is not valid. You cannot change NSDictionaries because they are immutable, it SHOULD be NSMutableDictionary.

HOWEVER if you are not interested in putting back the modified version into the original dictionary then you can copy it but as a NSMutableDictionary first, and then change it.

```
NSMutableDictionary *mutableDict = [[NSDictionary_B objectForKey:@"Random"] mutableCopy];

track.playbackType = mutableDict; //Note how track.playbackType has to be NSMutableDictionary aswell.
```

**VERY IMPORTANT:** Since you are creating a "new" dictionary. **track.playbackType** has to be strong, or it will simply get instantly dealocated after the function ends and **mutableDict** gets out of scope.

Comment: thanks, got it! I wasn't even considering the immutable part.

Answer (score 0):

References are just pointers, setting one to nil will have no effect except in the following case:  It is the last strong reference and other weak references still exist.  In that case all the weak references will become nil.  Strong properties will set the old value to nil, in effect sending a release call but this affects the REFERENCE, not the CONTENT of the reference.

As for the second question, it is quite confusing and I need more info about `playbackType`.  You say it is an NSDictionary but NSDictionary doesn't have the property `maxRange` so it must be a type that you defined.  You can't change the values of an NSDictionary either because it is immutable.

But here is a generic answer:  If you pass a pointer to a mutable object as strong (or weak even) you will be able to change the content of the original.  If you pass a pointer to a mutable object as a copy you will get a new object that doesn't affect the original.